# What URL should i use?

Tags: geoserver

By using the code below, we can query featureSet to ArcGIS Sample Server.

```
queryTask = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3");
```

I have published data on Geoserver by REST service.
1. Can I make this type of query (QueryTask) to Geoserver ?
2. What URL string should I use?

As I understood, the URL should be ("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/"), but I don't know the complete URL. I mean what should I append with the URL after /rest/..... Can anybody explain the complete format of the URL?

Comment: "services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3"

Answer (score 2):

No - GeoServer's REST interface is not the same as ESRI's REST interface. If you want to use standards based services such as GeoServer's WSM/WFS I recommend you switch to an opensource project like OpenLayers which cares about standards rather than re-inventing the wheel and hoping that your gorilla is big enough to drag the rest of us along.

Comment: Thanks for guidance!. Can i benefit same type of features like querytask and many other functions that Esri provides if i use Openlayers ?. My requirement is to query the features and attribute data and i also want to update features and attribute data by using feature and attribute update method while working on web. Esri provide all this functionality. Is all that functionality provided by OpenLayers ?. If Openlayers does nto support Quarytask, then its useless for me. please guide further.

Comment: what does querytask do?